# How to extend object with no setters to obtain superclass state

Tags: java, oop

I am extending a class to store some extra fields that I need to my application, but the class I am extending has no setter methods, and just a default constructor.

[http://restfb.com/javadoc/com/restfb/types/Post.html#Post()](http://restfb.com/javadoc/com/restfb/types/Post.html#Post%28%29)

I am using a framework that requires the getters to be in a correct naming format as the fields in the type. However, as I cannot set the fields from the constructor, or from setters,  I have kept a local copy of the initial object that I wish to store in my new object.

I then have overridden the methods to pull the data from the initial object as follows:

```
@Override
public String getMessage() {
    return initialPost.getMessage();
}
```

This does not seem like a good way to do things, one annoying reason being that I would have to override every method if I wish to use all fields.

What is the best way to solve this issue? Would this be a use case for composition over inheritance?

I think I may have tried to combine both here, which seems incorrect!

```
public class MyPost extends Post{

private String postId;
private Post initialPost;
private PostType type;
private Brand brand;
private Product product;
private List<Photo.Image> postImages;
```

Thanks for all advice.

Comment: Are you using composition or inheritance? By saying you "extend it", you indicate inheritance but the code implies composition.

Comment: I think I have combined both things, added in the declaration.

Comment: I have no setters for me to create the object, as Post is immutable, so I used composition to solve this. But I also want my new object to be of type Post, hence the inheritance. 
My question was what is the best approach to deal with a situation like this.

Comment: Is the framework actually going to use the setters, or do they just need to exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You indeed combined both composition and inheritance; which is a pretty confusing situation. I would go with inheritance since you are extending the behaviour of an object with a more specific purpose to just that object.

This also solves your problem because a `public` method from the `Post` class is also available as a `public` method from its subclasses (and as such, the framework can happily use `getMessage()` without you having to redefine it).

From my comment below:

> `Post` is essentially an immutable object so it is not intended to be constructed by you. You could override the methods from `Post` in `MyPost` and add your own getters/setters, but you should reflect whether or not this is an approach you want to take.

An example of how you would implement this:

```
class Post {
    private String body;

    public String getBody() {
        return body;
    }
}

class MyPost extends Post {
    private String body;

    public void setBody(String body) {
        this.body = body;
    }

    @Override    
    public String getBody() {
        return body;
    }
}
```

Now the `getBody()` method from the `Post` class is overridden by the selfdefined one from `MyPost`.

Comment: The problem though, is that I cannot set any of the fields of the initial post object. I have no setter, or constructors as it seems to be a totally immutable object. I want it to be of type Post, but to store all of the initial post data with my new object.

Comment: `Post` is essentially an immutable object so it is not intended to be constructed by you. You *could* override the methods from `Post` in `MyPost` and add your own getters/setters, but you should reflect whether or not this is an approach you want to take.

Comment: This is what I have done with my solution, but I was not sure if that was the best way to achieve this. Because Post is immutable, is this the best solution?

Comment: That's not exactly what you did: you also have a `Post` object as a field - this is not necessary. Without access to the `Post` class: yes, this is the best option I believe.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel, I like your solution, but how should user1089599 write setter methods? Can you give an example?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't more clear, what I meant was "how should setter methods be written for fields that are part of the super class?"

Comment: @randomducks: that is what I edited. You're basically hiding the implementation of `body` in your superclass by redefining it inside the subclass.

Comment: Ah, okay. Sorry, I didn't consider re-defining the private fields in the subclass.